# how to add dynamic arguments to urls in django

Tags: python, django, url

i have a website ,i let the user manager his account .

in his account page ,it will show all the articles he submitted .

to make it simple ,i let he can choose show how many articles in one page.by default is only show 10 articles in one page ,it is done by django pagination function ,if the user want to show 20 articles in one page, i add the arguments to current urls .

for example : `?num=20`

then for the second page the url should be `?num=20&page=2`

the problem is ,once it click page next button ,the url change to ?page=2,there is no num arguments pass to django.

and there are more arguments i need pass to django ,like only show articles that in subject in sports,so i should add one more arguments ,like

```
?num=20&sub=sport&page=2
```

but how can i make it work?

all i know is just give every argument a parameter ,like

```
url(_(r'^post/(?P<num>\w+)/(?P<sub>\w+)/(?P<page>\w+)/$'), views.post, ),
```

how can i design the url for this ? if i have about 5 arguments need to post .

Comment: You use POST type of request? or post is just name?

Comment: I don't think you can have url queries as a part of urls.py regex. The regex is always there to resolve the main URL. So, you'll just have to make sure that your links have ?num=20 appended to them inside your templates e.g. {% url 'post' %}?num=20

Comment: post is a name not POST

Answer (score 1):

If you use URL arguments like `?num=20&sub=sport&page=2` you have them in `request.GET`.

`print request.GET['num'], request.GET['sub'] request.GET['page']`

You can create your own variable like:

```
def test_func(request):
   next_page_url = '%s?page=%s' % (request.path, int(request.GET['page'] + 1) if 'page' in request.GET else '%s?page=2' % (request.path)

   return dict(next_page_url=next_page_url)
```